# Axios call gives infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to fetch some data and set the state, but it gives me infinite loop and I don't know how to fix this.

example in my Routes.tsx:

```
// get all posts
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('/api/posts', config)
            .then(res => setAllPosts(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [config]);
```

if I don't put 'config' in dependency, it will show results only on refresh, but then it wont give me infinite loop.

here is my project: https://github.com/marinavrataric/social_network

Answer (score 1):

Try using useStata[] with useEffect[]

```
   const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
     
      useEffect(async () => {
        const result = await axios.get('/api/posts', config)
            .then(res => setAllPosts(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
     
        setData(result);
      }, []);
     
      return (
        <ul>
          {data.posts.map(item => (
// stuff
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling your API in useEffect and also updating the state in useEffect too,  and useEffect without dependency is called every time the component renders, so here is the loop:

** call the  useEffect  >  call API> updating state using  setState>   as the state is update,  call the useEffect  **

So you need to add a dependency for useEffect which is not changed by the setState.  And then, whenever the value of the dependentis changed, the API will be called.

BTW, its better not to implement API call in useEffect. Rather You should try using readux and thunk.

Comment: so which dependency should i use instead?

Comment: It depends on use case.  If you want to call the API on first load, then you have use redux and thunk. If not, then if you want to call the api after a certain state is updated, rather than allPost, use that as dependency